# Rename-Refactoring XText Resource

Tags: xtext, xtend, language-server-protocol, theia, theia-ide

I am trying to perform rename-refactoring on XText resource. And have added
`fragment = refactoring.RefactorElementNameFragment2 {}` to the dsl `.mwe2`.

When I am trying to rename existing EAttribute the corresponding reference of this EAttribute is not
being refactored.

Is there something additionally that needs to be done.

additionally my project uses `eclipse-theia` as ide.

Also, How can I enable the Refactoring option in Theia-text editor.
[Theia-Editor Refactoring Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMJnR.png)

Comment: what do you mean by When I am trying to rename existing EAttribute the corresponding reference of this EAttribute is not being refactored. can you give more context

Comment: @ChristianDietrich  I have created an emf resource R1 that has an attribute name. This emf resource is referenced from some other resource R2. 

When I am renaming the resource R1, the corresponding reference to resource R2 is not updated to reflect the new name.

Comment: again. are you rename a file or an element in a file e.g. `entity Person` rename to `entity Person2`

Comment: @ChristianDietrich I am renaming an element.

Comment: this should work. can you give something reproducible?